# Envió de imágenes desde Vue a Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito enviar los datos de un formulario desde vue a laravel, pero ademas en este formulario se debe anexar una imagen para guardar, el problema me surge que al momento de enviar la imagen, esta nunca llega, dejo un ejemplo de lo que hago:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="img" class="form-control" @change="getImg" accept="image/*">
```

VUE:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("manifiesto", this.manifiesto);
axios.post('{{ route("compras.store") }}', {formData, factura: this.factura, productos: this.productos})
```

LARAVEL:

```
if ($request->hasFile('manifiesto')) {
  $path = $request->file('manifiesto')->store('manifiestos');
}
```

Lo raro es que si envio por axios de esta manera la imagen si llega:

```
axios.post('{{ route("compras.store") }}', formData)
```

si pueden apreciar en esta ultima linea de codigo solo estoy enviando la imagen pero no el objeto con los datos del formulario... sin embargo requiero esos datos tambien, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Primero adjuntas al formData los datos y la imagen asi.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("data",  JSON.stringify(this.data));
formData.append("image", this.image);
```

y en axios envias un header

```
axios.post('{{ route("compras.store") }}',formData,  {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
})
```

y en laravel

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $path = $request->file('image');
  $data = json_decode($request->data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Has probado a directamente añadir todo en el formData? Algo así?

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('factura', this.factura);
formData.append('productos', this.productos)
formData.append("manifiesto", this.manifiesto);
axios.post('{{ route("compras.store") }}',formData)
```

Comment: si amigo, lo hice tal cual pero en mi controlador de laravel cuando voy a ver los datos me sale de la siguiente manera:                                         
  "factura" => "[object Object]"
  "productos" => "[object Object]"                                                                         e intentado de acceder a los datos de deiferentes maneras y no lo he logrado, tambien necesito que cada objeto llegue con sus datos independientes..

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que hago para enviar es parsear mi data a string usando JSON.stringify()

```
const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(this.data));
 formData.append("image", this.images[0])
```

Ahora en axios no te olvides de pasar el header: "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"

```
axios.post('{{ route("compras.store") }}',formData,  {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
})
```

En laravel para recibir la informacion adicional

```
  $data =  json_decode($request->data)
```